# Emma Coverage Report not generated

Tags: maven, emma

I have a springboot project. I am trying to get emma coverage report for the project.

**Method 1:** 
I executed **mvn emma:emma** command on it. Coverage.em file has been generated. I dont know what to do with it

**Method 2:**

```
<reporting>
    <plugins>   
      <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>    
    <configuration>
          <dependencyLocationsEnabled>false</dependencyLocationsEnabled>
    </configuration>
      </plugin>     
      <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>emma-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-alpha-3</version>
    <inherited>true</inherited>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
```

I have added the above piece of code to pom.xml and ran **mvn site** command.
site folder had been created with some contents in it. I tried to open up index.html, i could see the list of things like project summary, dependencies etc. I clicked on Project Reports and then Emma Coverage Report. Then it showed up page can't be displayed. It is trying to access the path **C:\Full Stack Development\ProjectManagement\target\site\emma\index.html** . The folder emma is empty.

[Screenshot of page displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYhvR.png)

**Method 3:**

I have added the following plugin using build tag. Same happened as in method 2.

```
<build>         
    <plugins>    
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>emma-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-alpha-3</version>
        <inherited>true</inherited>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>instrument</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
     </plugin>              
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: I strongly recommend not to use emma-maven-plugin from codehaus anymore cause it's about 10 years old...better use JaCoCo it's more up-to-date etc. apart from that I suppose you are using an up-to-date version of Spring Boot (2.X)...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I too figured out that its very outdated